# Is there a way to kill processes that are going to be listed after running grep

Tags: terminal, grep, kill, osx-yosemite

For e.g. if we have to check all the glassfish processes running we run the following command:

ps aux | grep glassfish

Now for e.g. it returns 4 processes that glassfish is occupying is there a way to edit the command and store it in bash_profile that it will kill all the processes that were the output of running the **ps aux | grep glassfish**

For e.g. if I store an alias in **bash_profile** as **killglass** then it should kill all the processes that were returned when I run the **ps aux | grep glassfish** command from the terminal

I am run MAC(Yosemite)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

> pkill -f "glassfish"

Instead of ps aux and grep

Comment: Oops I didnt know it was that simple.. thanks a lot. Ill try it.